# Sorting a sub-section of a file

Tags: perl, sorting

I'm in need of some Perl wisdom from those more experienced than myself.

So far, my answer to the below is to simply go through the file line-by line, and insert relevant elements into an array, sort the array and then append the contents.   But that seems like a bit long-winded and not very efficient.

I have a file whose contents look something like this :

```
# A Comment
# Another comment
:127.100.100.255:Something
.789
.123
.456
:127.200.200.100:Something Else
.bravo.example.com   # <----
noperiod.example.com # <----  This list is
.an.example.com      # <----  not ordered
.some.example.com    # <----
```

Is there a clever way in Perl (ideally a one-liner that could be piped) to sort the second list ?  i.e. so you would get the following result :

```
# A Comment
# Another comment
:127.100.100.255:Something
.789
.123
.456
:127.200.200.100:Something Else
.an.example.com        # <----
.bravo.example.com     # <---- NOW this list
noperiod.example.com   # <---- IS ordered ;-)
.some.example.com      # <----
```

Four things  to note :

1. The content to be sorted is always at the bottom of the file
2. The header (":127.200.200.100 etc.") is always the same
3. Names may or may not start with a period (i.e. .bravo.example.com vs noperiod.example.com)
4. There may be a large number of items, so needs to be reasonably efficient

Comment: Do periods 'count'? E.g. '.bravo' = 'b' but 'noperiod' = 'n'? And ... fundamentally no, you cannot sort a data set without reading the whole data set - otherwise how would you know if the last line needed to be output first?

Comment: No, periods don't count for sorting ... as per example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort that by the shell with a little help from Perl: Just prepend a line number to each line *before* the list, and for the list, use the number of its first line. Then sort numerically by the numbers, and secondary by the rest of the line:

```
perl -ne 'if (1 .. /^:127\.200\.200\.100:.*/) {
              print "$.\t$_";
          } else {
              print $.--, "\t$_"
          }' file.txt \
| sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by 'efficient'. I mean, a one liner is rarely *efficient* and it's also rarely concise or clear as to what it's doing.

But in terms of efficiency? Well, it depends what you're doing already that's inefficient. I mean, pretty fundamentally, if you're sorting something you need to examine the whole data set. Otherwise how would you know that the last line in your file needs to be sorted to the top?

But for what you're doing, I'd approach it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub sort_noperiods {
   my $a_np = $a;
      $a_np =~ s/\.//g;
   my $b_np = $b; 
      $b_np =~ s/\.//g; 

   return $a_np cmp $b_np;
}

while ( <> ) { 
   print;
   last if m/Something Else/;
}

print sort sort_noperiods <>;
```

Which for your sample input, prints:

```
# A Comment
# Another comment
:127.100.100.255:Something
.789
.123
.456
:127.200.200.100:Something Else
.an.example.com      # <----  not ordered
.bravo.example.com   # <----
noperiod.example.com # <----  This list is
.some.example.com    # <----
```

I'm keying off the 'Something Else' line in your file, as I couldn't quite tell how you'd identify the last line of the 'header' chunk. Anything else gets read in and sorted according to the 'noperiods' sort mechanism. (There may be a small efficiency gain by caching the result of the regular expressions, but I'm not sure of this).

This can be 'one-linerified' by:

```
perl -e 'while ( <> ) { print; last if m/Something Else/ }; print sort { $a =~ s/\.//gr cmp $b =~ s/\.//gr } <>; '
```